# How to get the affected rows number of Linq To Sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How to get the affected rows number of Linq To Sql?

I use Linq To Sql to delete a batch of records in the sql server 2005.

How can I get the affected rows number?

And How can I know how many records have been deleted if that is something wrong happened in the batch delete?

Answer (score 3):

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    db.Stuff.InsertOnSubmit(stuff);
    int rowsInserted = db.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Count;
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The GetChangeSet() method also contains updates & deletes, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a function that would get the number of rows affected.

```
public int updateDB(int ID){
        List<Person> people = db.Person.Where(i => i.ID > ID).ToList();

        foreach(Person p in people)
            p.Name = "John";

        return db.SaveChanges(); //return the number of rows affected
    }
```

Comment: db.SaveChanges is for EF, not for Linq2SQL?